# Paint image on ios Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm working on application for kids. In this application, I'would like to allow children to draw what they want, or to fill region with a color. For drawing I use something like in this code [stackoverflow.com/questions/17219426/building-an-app-with-an-electronic-signature-feature-for-ios-possibly-using-mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219426/building-an-app-with-an-electronic-signature-feature-for-ios-possibly-using-mono)

Now I would like to fill region with a color

I found this code for android, I would like to convert it for iOS (xamarin)

`
    private void FloodFill(Bitmap bmp, Point pt, int targetColor, int replacementColor)
    {

```
    Queue<Point> q = new LinkedList<Point>();
    q.add(pt);

    while (q.size() > 0) {
        Point n = q.poll();
        if (bmp.getPixel(n.x, n.y) != targetColor)
            continue;
        Point w = n, e = new Point(n.x + 1, n.y);

        while ((w.x > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y) == targetColor)) 
        {
            bmp.setPixel(w.x, w.y, replacementColor);
            if ((w.y > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y - 1) == targetColor))
                q.add(new Point(w.x, w.y - 1));
            if ((w.y < bmp.getHeight() - 1) && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y + 1) == targeteColor))
                q.add(new Point(w.x, w.y + 1));
            w.x--;
        }

        while ((e.x < bmp.getWidth() - 1)&& (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y) == targetColor)) 
        {
            bmp.setPixel(e.x, e.y, replacementColor);
            if ((e.y > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y - 1) == targetColor))
                q.add(new Point(e.x, e.y - 1));
            if ((e.y < bmp.getHeight() - 1) && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y + 1) == targetColor))
                q.add(new Point(e.x, e.y + 1));
            e.x++;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Any help or comment is welcome

Thank you

Comment: I recommend to check out this wikipedia page about Flood fill algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) (example pseudocode). In my opinion it would be easier to implement by yourself with recursion.